# Trace of Invertible Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $P$and $Q$ are two invertible matrices such that $PQ=-QP$ then prove that
tr(P)=-tr(Q).
(tr denote trace of a matrix)

Given $PQ=-QP \Rightarrow$ $Q$ is similar to $-Q$ hence $tr(Q)=tr(-Q)\Rightarrow$$tr(Q)=0$.
        Similarly we can prove $tr(P)=0$ But how to prove $tr(P)=-tr(Q)?$

Comment: But is this only reason?

Comment: Are you looking for an explanation that $\def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}\tr(P)=-\tr(Q)$ would hold even if both sides were nonzero, in spite of the fact that you proved that they _are_ zero?

Answer (score 2):

$PQ=-QP$ implies that $P=-QPQ^{-1}$, so that $P$ and $-P$ are similar, and $Q$ and $-Q$ are similar. This implies $2{\rm tr}(P)=2{\rm tr}(Q)=0$. If the field has characteristic different from two, this gives
$$
{\rm tr}(P)=0=-{\rm tr}(Q).
$$

Comment: So you are basically saying: in characteristic $2$ the result claimed is false (well actually you don't say that, but it is easy to see), and otherwise the reasoning given in the question itself is valid.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Yes, you are right.